# Can you return the value of an expression in python, like in C++? or not

Tags: python

I am a bit confused, I would appreciate the kind of immediate resolution that SO is so good for. For some reason this code...

```
def process(self, command):
    return (command == "Quit" or "quit" or "Q" or "q")
```

... produces the same output in my program that does this...

```
def process(self, command):
    return True
```

What?? However, this code performs as I expect it to:

```
def process(self, command):
    return (command == "Quit")
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What did you expect? You can't do this in C++ either. You need `command =="Q" or command == "q"...`

Comment: is `command in ('Quit','quit','Q','q')` what you are trying to do?

Comment: What does the question name have to do with the description? Clearly you're returning the value of an expression in `return (command == "Quit")`, so… are you actually confused about that?

Comment: It seemed conditional, or more like schizophrenic. I'd change the name of the question now, but it seems superfluous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's pick this apart a bit:

```
>>> command = 'foo'
>>> command == "Quit" or "quit" or "Q" or "q"
'quit'
```

This is because of how the `or` operator works.  It looks for the first True-like value and returns it.  If it doesn't find one, it returns `False`.

Your command here is parsed as:

```
((((command == "Quit") or "quit") or "Q") or "q")
```

So, parsing from left to right, if `command` doesn't equal `"Quit"`, you have:

```
(((False or "quit") or "Q") or "q")
```

But here, `"quit"` is a non-empty string, so python considers it "True-like" so it is what gets returned.

---

Now that we know *why* it doesn't work, lets look at how to fix it:

The canonical way to do something like this is to use the `in` operator on some object which supports it:

```
def process(self, command):
    return command in ("Quit","quit","Q","q")
```

Tuple's are nice (and they'll perform better than a list).  However, if you're going to use it over and over, a `set` will perform the fastest provided that you can avoid building it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

```
def process(self, command):
    return command in ("Quit" , "quit" , "Q" , "q")
```